# Correlate and Sum Table Data as Summary

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

I want to summarize rows from one end of a relationship tree with a table on the other side. Is "correlate" the correct term? Really just knowing the terms would help me solve this problem.

I am using MySQL and am extending an existing DB structure - though would have the liberty to rearrange data if needed. I'm getting better at creating "filtering" queries using `JOIN`s, and I'm sure this next piece will be straight-forward once I understand it (without performing tons of queries : )

I made a simplified schema (and theme!) for this example, but the idea is the same.

Say there are many `DietPlan`s, which is related to a bunch of `MenuItems` and each `MenuItem` has an `ItemType` (such as 'Healthy','Fast','Normal', etc.) On the other side of `DietPlan` there are `Person`s, who each store how many `DailyCalories` they consume, and another table `MenuAllocations`, where a `Person` stores how much percent of their daily intake is from what `MenuItem`.

As examples of scale, There could be 1000 `MenuItems`, and 50 of those associated with each of 200 `DietPlan`s. Also, each `DietPlan` might have 10,000 `Person`s, who each will have 5-10 `MenuAllocations` of various types.

[image: Table layout in MySQL Workbench]

What I'd like to do feels complex to me. I want to create a dashboard for each `DietPlan` (there could be many), gathering data from the `Person`s of that `DietPlan`, and tabulating the **number of calories for each item type.**

The math is simple: `tblPerson.dailyCalories` * `tblMenuAllocations.percent`. But I want to do that for each `Person` in the `DietPlan`, for each `ItemType`.

I understand the `JOIN`s required to 'filter' from `tblItemType` around to `tblMenuAllocation` and think it would be similar to this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tblMenuAllocation
 INNER JOIN tblPerson
    on personId = PersonId
 INNER JOIN tblDietPlan
    on tblPerson.dietPlanId = tblDietPlan.DietPlanId
 INNER JOIN tblMenuItem
    on tblMenuItem.dietPlanId = tblDietPlan.DietPlanId
 INNER JOIN tblItemTyp
    on ItemTypeId = itemTypeId
 WHERE ItemTypeId = 2
```

It feels like one query for each `tblItemType`, which could be a **LOT** of `Person` and `MenuAllocation` data to sort through, and doing that many consecutive queries feels like I'm missing something. Also, I think math can be handled in the query to sum values, but I've never done that. Where can I begin?

**EDIT:** The final results would be something like this:

```
 ----------------------------------------------
 ItemId   |  ItemDesc  |   TotalCalories     
 ----------------------------------------------
 1          Healthy       450,876
 2          Fast          1,987,948
 3          Vegan         349,123
 etc.
```

I would be willing to accept some manipulation of data outside the query, but the `Person`'s specific `dailyCalories` is very important to the `tblMenuAllocation.percent` calculation. Some `tblMenuAllocation` rows might be of the same `ItemType`!

Comment: Can you give the expected result columns? (table and field name or computation)

Comment: Putting in answer, formatting didn't work great here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for these topics :
[Aggregate Functions](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx) and
[Group By Modifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Comment: A long time in coming, but this was the correct answer and the topics I needed. A little trial and error with the JOINs, but that's how data is bridged (and combined) across many related tables (even distantly related tables!).